# Where is error log in Looking Glass in gnome shell 3.6?

Tags: gnome, 12.10

Where is error log ("Errors" tab) in Looking Glass in gnome shell 3.6 (ubuntu 12.10)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For everyone coming here with a similar problem. After research I found out for Gnome Shell 3.20.4 the errors are logged via journalctl

```
journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-session -f
```

If this (recommended command by gnome) does not help (like for me) use this command instead:

```
journalctl -xe
```

Answer (score 1):

> In 3.4 and earlier, there was an errors tab that showed you some
>   errors and logging statements extensions, but not all of them: some JS
>   errors were instead logged to stderr, which was usually transferred to
>   your session log. If you weren't aware, you were blindly debugging.
>
> In 3.6, all errors are now emitted to stderr, which should be
>   available through your session log, if you are running gnome-shell
>   from a session. The session log is available in
>   ~/.cache/gdm/session.log on GDM 3.6, and ~/.xsession-errors with most
>   other display managers.

[Source](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/LookingGlass#Errors)